# A mirror of events

Tags: riddle

This is where yesterday follows tomorrow, departure follows arrival, front follows back, start follows end, past follows future and even life follows death.

What is it?

Comment: A bit of a consistency error helped me out: "This is *where*" turned to "*what* is it?"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> A dictionary.  The word 'yesterday' comes after 'tomorrow' in a dictionary. The word 
>  'departure' comes after 'arrival' in a dictionary. And so on...

Answer (score 5):

> Only an English-language dictionary, in general.
>
> For bonus points, here are some other languages where this does not hold: denoting "follows" by '>' and "doesn't follow" by '>#' :
>
> French: hier > demain, départ > arrivé, devant ># envers, début ># fin, passé > avenir, vie > mort
>
> German: gestern ># morgen, Abfahrt ># Ankunft, Vorderseite > Rückseite, Anfang ># Ende,  Vergangenheit ># Zukunft, Leben ># Tod/Sterben
>
> Hence we could characterize any language with a 6-digit binary number (although the choice of words is in some cases subjective, as in whether 'front' vs 'back' refers to the human body or 'obverse'/'reverse' etc.)

Comment: Can anyone please fix my spoiler tags??

Comment: I tried to, but it only broke them a bit further (and if my edit gets passed, you should reverse it). I think spoiler quotes might be one line only, or there's a bug.

Comment: [I've reported the bug on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243008/spoiler-quotes-break-when-multiple-lines-get-involved)

Comment: Thanks for your help with formatting guys. The short answer is `>!` can only be used for spoilers, not for anything else. So in my case I used `>#` to denote 'does not follow'.

Answer (score 3):

> I would guess a dictionary. All the first words of those pairs are lexicographically after the second words.